# Sorting deque with a function

Tags: c++, sorting, deque

I need to sort a deque of std::pair, and then print out their original unsorted iterator values, however when I try to use the following code:

```
// I have used pii instead of pair<int,int> by using typedef
inline bool comparison(pii & lval, pii & rval) {
        return (lval.first < rval.first);
    } // and a few lines down
sort(v.begin(),v.end(), comparison);
```

I get the following error:

> error C2664: 'bool (pii &,pii &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const int' to 'pii &'

I can't seem to understand where I'm going wrong, can someone figure out the mistake?
If you want to see the full code, here:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <deque>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> pii;

inline void get_input(deque<pii> place, const int & size) {
    pii temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &temp.first);
        temp.second = i;
        place.push_back(temp);
    }
}

inline bool comparison(pii & lval, pii & rval) {
    return (lval.first < rval.first);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    deque<pii> v1, v2;
    get_input(v1, n);
    get_input(v2, n);
    sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), comparison);
    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), comparison);
    /* I am aware that the part where I print the values of
    the iterators is missing, I didn't want to add unimportant
    bulk to the question */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The full example compiles fine for me. What compiler are you using and what are your compiler flags?

Comment: Note that `inline` doesn't necessarily cause the function to be inlined, nor does the absence of the `inline` keyword prevent inlining. I'd be curious as to see which compilers manage to inline `comparison` in the call to `sort`.

Comment: You could also make the signature `comparison(const pii&, const pii&)` as well.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC, I don't know about compiler flags however.

Comment: @Joshua compiles fine with current version of VS2017(15.2)

Comment: The signature `comparison(const pii&, const pii&)` makes more semantic sense anyway -- you're not modifying either argument, there is no reason for them to not be const.

Comment: Having said that, the error doesn't really make sense. Note that it's saying it can't convert `const int` to `pii &`. Where is this `int` coming from!?

Comment: Maybe it could just be some problem with my compiler, I'll try to repair VS. @FrançoisAndrieux Could you possibly link me to the information that you mentioned about the inline keyword above?

Comment: Another issue, `get_input()` should take its first argument by reference, otherwise you are giving it a copy of your deques, it will populate the copy and then destroy the copy, leaving the original deques in `main()` empty.

Comment: @cdhowie Thank You for the correction :)

Comment: @Joshua `inline` has evolved to mean "multiple definitions are permitted". It's at most a hint to the compiler. See [inline specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). It says *"Since this meaning of the keyword inline is non-binding, compilers are free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked inline, and are free to generate function calls to any function marked inline."*

Comment: @Joshua Inlining is not free, it has positive and negative consequences. Rather or not it's worth to inline code depends on how and where you use the function, not just on it's body. The existence of the keyword implies that only the body matters and it's one of the reasons it's no longer used for it's original meaning. The compiler will know best when to inline and when the cost outweighs the benefits.

Comment: @Joshua is there any reason to use `v1.end()` here  `sort(v2.begin(), v1.end(), comparison);` instead `v2.end()`?

Comment: @segevara That was a typo I made when writing the question, fixed it though, thanks :)

Comment: I thought std::sort only worked with random access iterators.  std::deque iterators are not random access, [oh no.  they are now

Comment: @MichaëlRoy they always have been random access, although they require an extra level of indirection compared to std::vector iterators. I wish I had time to try this code sample myself, because I can't imagine why `std::sort` would be calling the comparison with an `int` parameter.

Comment: I saw that. I stand corrected. thanks.